# Hibernate updates entities

Tags: hibernate

I get entities from DB using HQL request:

```
List<Entity> entities = getSession().createQuery("...").list();
```

Then I made some changes with returned object to return it to user via JSON. For example:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    entity.setParentId(null);
}
```

And return it to user. I don't call update methods etc. But when session is completed, my all entities get ParentId with null value!

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your entities when they are `detached` objects which means outside the `transactional` context or when the `session` is closed,other than that it still considered to be `persistent` instances and the changes will be committed to database when the `session` is closed.